# firebug points to jquery error but I do not know how to resolve the error

Tags: jquery, firebug, conflict

I believe there is a jquery conflict on my site. But I do not understand how to use firebug to debug it.

When clicking on the "Calculate Shipping and Handling link" from our cart page, the results never show.

To do this you need to first add an item to your cart at http://www.musicforte.com/sheet_music/ and then click on "Cart" at the top right of the page.

What I see in firebug when viewing "console" with "persist" is a red x and that there is an error on jquery.js line 141.

How can I understand where the conflict is and resolve it?

I modified the code to include an id to the Calculate Shipping button as suggested, but still having no luck.  Here is the code being used:

I tried adding an ID to the Calculate Shipping button.  But it did not solve the problem. I modified the code to read:

```
<a href="#" class="EstimateShippingLink" onclick="Cart.ToggleShippingEstimation(); return false;"><em>%%LNG_CalculateShippingHandling%%</em></a>
                        <div class="EstimateShipping" style="display: none;">
                            <div class="EstimatedShippingMethods" style="display: none;">
                                <div class="ShippingMethodList">
                                </div>
                                <hr />
                            </div>
                            <dl>
                                <dt>%%LNG_Country%%:</dt>
                                <dd>
                                    <select style="width:200px;" name="shippingZoneCountry" id="shippingZoneCountry" onchange="Cart.ToggleShippingEstimateCountry();">
                                        %%GLOBAL_ShippingCountryList%%
                                    </select>
                                </dd>

                                <dt>%%LNG_StateProvince%%:</dt>
                                <dd>
                                    <select style="display: %%GLOBAL_ShippingHideStateList%%" style="width:200px;" name="shippingZoneState" id="shippingZoneState">
                                        %%GLOBAL_ShippingStateList%%
                                    </select>
                                    <input style="display: %%GLOBAL_ShippingHideStateBox%%" type="text" class="Textbox Field200" name="shippingZoneStateName" id="shippingZoneStateName" value="%%GLOBAL_AddressState%%" />
                                </dd>

                                <dt>%%LNG_ZipPostcode%%:</dt>
                                <dd><input type="text" class="Field100 Textbox" name="shippingZoneZip" id="shippingZoneZip" value="%%GLOBAL_ShippingZip%%" /></dd>
                            </dl>
                            <p class="Submit EstimateShippingButtons">
                                <span style="display:inline-block;padding-right: 10px;vertical-align:top;"><a href="#" onclick="Cart.ToggleShippingEstimation();">%%LNG_Cancel%%</a> %%LNG_or%% </span><input type="image" class="formBtn" src="%%GLOBAL_TPL_PATH%%/images/%%GLOBAL_SiteColor%%/CalculateShipping.gif" onclick="Cart.EstimateShipping();" value="%%LNG_CalculateShipping%%" id="fixshipping" />
                            </p>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Put at least a screenshot here

Comment: You'd also want to pay attention to the status code shown in Firebug. It's the status code returned from the server for the request; a 500 error indicates there was an exception on the server side, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are embedding the module inside the form and when you click the image input it is doing browser default and is submitting the whole form, not just your shipping fields, and causes page to reload.

The error I believe is due to ajax being aborted.

I ran this in console and was able to get the shipping calcs returned without page reloading, or error

```
$('.EstimateShippingButtons input').click(function(){
   return false;
})
```

You may want to improve selector, perhaps add an ID to your shiiping calcs submit button

EDIT: actually just need to add `return false` or `event.preventDefault()` to your existing handler

In cart.js add it to end of Cart.EstimateShipping

Comment: added function you need to modify at bottom of my answer

Comment: I must be doing this wrong.  In cart.js I now have:
    $('.EstimateShipping .EstimateShippingButtons input').click(function(){return false;})

That is near the end of the function.  Did I do that wrong?

Comment: just add `return false;` to end of function

Comment: ok.  Just before the closing curly bracket, I added return false;  But the problem still exists.

Comment: try just using my code then within a jQuery ready event block

Comment: I don't understand how to do that. I'm sorry.  I did run what you have provided above in the firebug console, and it then worked perfectly for me, too.  I wish firebug, showed the modified code so I could copy and paste.  The places I have tried above did not work.